# How can I know if R is running on 64 bits versus 32?

Tags: r, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

My version output is:

```
> version
               _                            
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32           
arch           x86_64                       
os             mingw32                      
system         x86_64, mingw32              
status                                      
major          2                            
minor          15.2                         
year           2012                         
month          10                           
day            26                           
svn rev        61015                        
language       R                            
version.string R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
nickname       Trick or Treat
```

where os is mingw32. Does that mean I'm using only 32 bits? How can I change that?

Comment: Did you get the answer for this?I'm facing the same issue and I don't know how to proceed, Should the command Sys.getenv("R_ARCH") or Sys.info()[["machine"]] to be typed in R query window or on command prompt?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Here are a few ways:

- `Sys.getenv("R_ARCH")` returns either `"/i386"` or `"/x64"` at least on my Windows system (but not on my Ubuntu system where it returns an empty string)
- `Sys.info()[["machine"]]` returns `"x86_32"` or `"x86_64"` on my Windows and Ubuntu systems.

**Updated:** With additional method.

Comment: Mine returned `""`. :-/

Comment: Just  type R in terminal and have a look at the top of the text. Mine says: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit). The accepted answer does not work for me.

Comment: On R version 3.3.3, Sys.info()$machine return an error: "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors". This alternative works: Sys.info()["machine"].

Answer (score 51):

Rather than needing to remember the designations of various OS's, the canonical cross-platform method is to look at:

```
> .Machine$sizeof.pointer
[1] 8   # 8 bytes for address is 64 bits.
```

This is the address space for R objects. (It's not the address space for the OS.)

Answer (score 6):

You may have multiple versions of R installed. To change versions in RStudio: Tools -> Global Options -> R Version...Change...

I choose "Use the machine's default version of R64 (64-bit)," since my OS is Windows 8 x64.

Answer (score 5):

Your platform says `x86_64-w64` in front of the `mingw32`. Your arch is similarly `x86_64`. That means you're running 64-bit, on 64-bit Windows.

For reference, the corresponding arch for 32-bit R would be `i386`.

Comment: Also, if you're using the GUI version of R, the title bar will give the architecture: `(32-bit)` or `(64-bit)`.

Comment: That's probably a Windows only answer. Certainly not true of the Mac GUI.