# Can't load the mailR package in R

Tags: r, sendmailr

I would like to load mailR package in both my local rStudio and one run off an ec2 server. I get this error:

```
> require(mailR)
Loading required package: mailR
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘mailR’ was built under R version 3.3.3
```

If I try to load rJava I get:

```
> require(rJava)
Loading required package: rJava
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘rJava’ was built under R version 3.3.2
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: As the error says, try to reinstall `rJava`

Comment: I did and I got the following error.

Comment: Try running `R CMD javareconf` (from the console) and try again after that.

Comment: `R CMD javareconf` worked for me but in the terminal.

Comment: I had the same problem [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70417282/5783745) what worked.