# Unable to load RJDBC package in RStudio

Tags: r, rjdbc

I have successfully installed the RJDBC in RStudio.

```
install.packages("RJDBC")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/RJDBC_0.2-7.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 70232 bytes (68 KB)
downloaded 68 KB

package ‘RJDBC’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

However when I load RJDBC on Windows 7 64-bit. However I get the following error.

```
The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\abhish\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0oCqXi\downloaded_packages
> library(RJDBC)
Loading required package: rJava
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R Foundation/R/library/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified path is invalid.

Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘RJDBC’ was built under R version 3.4.3 
2: package ‘rJava’ was built under R version 3.4.3
```

Comment: Looks like a problem with `rJava`. Have a look here for a potential solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735108/r-error-onload-failed-in-loadnamespace-for-rjava