# "unable to load shared object" when loading the rJava library

Tags: java, r

I have to load an Excel file .xlsx on R, but:

```
library(xlsx)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
> .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
> call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
> error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/danil/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
> LoadLibrary failure:  Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.
> Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded

So, I tried to install Java, Java SE-Development Kit 10 and Java Runtime Environment 10, 64 bit for both. But, also in this case:

```
library(rJava)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
> .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
> call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
> error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/danil/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
> LoadLibrary failure:  Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.

What can I do?

Comment: Hi @francesco... welcome to SO. I've edited your title to be a bit more informative as a question.

Comment: No problem, i hope that it will also help anybody else.

Comment: How did you install xlsx package? Or have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/q/37735108/5784831

Comment: I wasnt'able to install xlsx package... It says "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’". I don't know what to do, i'm a newbie of R.

Comment: What is your OS? Usually, when I get these errors, I look all over the error messages, such often there will be some libraries/packages suggested for installing for each operating system.

Comment: I use Windows 10. And no errors were found during install.packages("xlsx") and install.packages("rJava"). The problem is after, when i try to charge Java package.

Comment: I am running R version Version 1.0.143 and Java version 1.8.0_161(latest)

Comment: Sorry, i running Windows 8. And: sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Italian_Italy.1252  LC_CTYPE=Italian_Italy.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Italian_Italy.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Italian_Italy.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.4 tools_3.4.4

Comment: Try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019912/using-the-rjava-package-on-win7-64-bit-with-r/15998358#15998358

Answer (score 2):

This was happening to me as well (also Windows 10), and the problem with mine was that the environment variable was not set properly. In my case, I had to do

```
Sys.setenv('JAVA_HOME' = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_161/')
```

Just change the folder name to where Java lives in your computer, and let me know if this doesn't work out.

Comment: Do you happen to know why do we need to setenv() for JAVA_HOME in R, when I had already set JAVA_HOME in system variables? Using Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 16.04 I did the following trick in RStudio:

`Sys.setenv('JAVA_HOME' = '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre')`

Surprisingly, but

`Sys.setenv('JAVA_HOME' = '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/')`

didn't work for me.