# Unable to load rJava on rStudio

Tags: r, rjava

When I run `library(rJava)` the following appears:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '//fsasydmsdepfs01/personal$/username/My Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘rJava’ was built under R version 4.0.3
```

I've tried ensuring that they're both 64 bit by setting the following

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = "C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_271")
```

Am really unclear what the issue seems to be and I've googled everything. Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R - Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735108/r-error-onload-failed-in-loadnamespace-for-rjava)

Comment: no it doesn't :( i've even tried to follow this guide step by step - https://cimentadaj.github.io/blog/2018-05-25-installing-rjava-on-windows-10/installing-rjava-on-windows-10/

Comment: Have you tried in `Rterm` instead of the RStudio IDE? If it works there, then this is a bug for RStudio support (community or otherwise). If it does not work there (as I suspect), then please remove the [tag:rstudio] tag, as that tag is only for IDE-related issues. Thanks!