# Problem in installing 'RMongo' throws rJava error even though library(rJava) works fine

Tags: r, mongodb

> install.packages("RMongo")

doesn't works (seems like it has been deprecated.
So, I was trying to install using devtools.

> devtools::install_github("tc/Rmongo")

but it gives out error

```
  Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rJava':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/saini/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rJava/libs/i386/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Error : package 'rJava' could not be loaded
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
Warning: package 'rJava' was built under R version 3.5.2
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
* removing 'C:/Users/saini/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/RMongo'
In R CMD INSTALL
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/saini/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpuEHfqO/file20f419985c01/RMongo_0.1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Even though library(rJava) works fine.
JDK, JRE are both 64 bit. R and R studio are also 64 bits.
Someone suggested to use

> R CMD javareconf

but it doesnot recongnises javareconf.

Also, I've set Environment Variables.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: RMongo is no longer maintained (last commits were in 2015) and has been unpublished from CRAN. I believe [mongolite](https://cran.r-project.org/package=mongolite) may be the only R driver for MongoDB that is actively maintained and compatible with modern versions of MongoDB.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091614/how-can-i-know-if-r-is-running-on-64-bits-versus-32 Since all errors seem to indicate this is a 32-bit install of R-Studio

Comment: @NeilLunn
 > Sys.getenv("R_ARCH") 
[1] "/x64"
> Sys.info()[["machine"]]
[1] "x86-64" this suggests that R is x64?

Comment: @StennieI guess I have to move to mongolite. Thanks